# Find the number of elements with same color (CSS Property)

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

There are few web elements in the list "bElements" with CSS Color property: "rgba(46, 162, 236, 1)"
How can I get the number of those elements that have  CSS Color property: "rgba(46, 162, 236, 1)" from "bElements". **Below code works,** but is there any way to get the count of elements that have same CSS Property.

```
bElements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/ul/li/a/span[2]")
element = 0
for num in range(len(bubbleelements)):
    if (bubbleelements[num].value_of_css_property('color')) == "rgba(46, 162, 236, 1)":
        element = element+1
print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use counter to return a dictionary whose values is the numbers of occurrences of each item in bElements list:

```
from collections import Counter
bElements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/divul/li/a/span[2]")
elements = Counter (bElements)
```